# Convert .dat file into pandas dataframe (tab delimited)

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

After downloading a .dat file, I am trying to convert it into a pandas df but it looks very strange when I run these lines of code:

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('HUMAN_9606_idmapping.dat',  sep ='\t', nrows=10)
```

```
df3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO('HUMAN_9606_idmapping.dat'), 
                 sep="\t", 
                 index_col=0, #convert first column to datetimeindex
                 header=None) #none header
```

File:
https://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/idmapping/by_organism/HUMAN_9606_idmapping.dat.gz

How can I convert it to look like a regular df?

Comment: How about trying '\s' as separator?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't separate the columns out correctly.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by *"very strange"*? Your second import seems to work fine.

Comment: It should have 10+ different columns, but only shows 3

Comment: It doesnt, open it in a text editor and you'll see

Comment: Why doesn't it show like that in jupyter notebook?